# fit div to img using css, not using js get the image size and set the div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the container to fit the size same as the containing image without explicitly set the width and height of image to container?

```
<div id="imageContainer" style="background-color:black">
<img id="image" src="11.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style>
#imageContainer{ display:inline-block; }
#image{ display:block; }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dBLsP/1/

To make it work in older browsers too you can use this:

```
<style>
#imageContainer{
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
</style>
```

[reference](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/)

Comment: Thank you, but the problem still not be solved, because there still is some extra div space at the bottom of the image, so the div is not completely fit to the image

Comment: Add #image{ display:block; } - Added to my answer

Comment: Your reference is from 2007 and pretty outdated. All recent browsers support `inline-block`.

Comment: Not everyone has a recent browser

Comment: Granted, IE6/7 accounts for [roughly 10%](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php?year=2011&month=9), but hacking for Mozilla before Firefox 3 (when `inline-block` support was  introduced) is probably fairly pointless as it doesn't seem to be in the statistics anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<style>
   .imageContainer{
      float:left;
    }
</style>
```

or

```
<style>
   .imageContainer{
       position: absolute
    }
</style>
```

or use another element that is inline like `<span>`

Comment: Span would work for the width but the height is normally set to 1em (I think)

Comment: "display:inline-block;" is not a crosbrowser solution

Comment: Thank you, but the problem still not be solved, because there still is some extra div space at the bottom of the image, so the div is not completely fit to the image

Comment: Why use another element that is inline? Setting `display: inline` is enough. Also, [all browsers except IE6/7 support `inline-block`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html), so I'd say it's fairly cross-browser.

Comment: Lots of people still use IE6/7 unfortunately